# Deciding the semantic role of an adverbial clause starting with "with"

Tags: adverbial-phrases, adverbials

The sentence at issue is

> When I woke up with my legs dangling over the side of the bed, my feet touched something other than the floor.

Could you help me determine whether "with my legs dangling over the side of the bed" is an adverbial clause of manner or and adverbial clause of accompaniment, or does it have an entirely different function? I have searched on the Internet but found very few examples of adverb clauses starting with "with", so further explanations would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Here "with" functions as a preposition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the part of speech of "with" is a preposition. But in this example it also serves as the beginning of an averbial clause, the function of which is what I want to focus on.

This is also similar to the example in https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_clauses.htm, where the preposition "after" starts an advertbial clause of time: "He lost his double chin after he gave up chocolate."

Comment: It's certainly an adjunct, but I'm not sure what semantic kind it is. Possibly comitative, or otherwise manner.

Comment: It might even be adjectival, performing the same function as "hungry" in this sentence: "I woke up hungry." (I don't favor that interpretation, but it's possible.)

Answer (score 1):

> When I woke up with my legs dangling over the side of the bed, my feet
> touched something other than the floor.

"With" is used here to express *manner*.  It expresses the way in which an action occurs.

"**She was walking around *with* an air of confidence.**"

"**I woke up *with* my legs dangling over the side of the bed**"

The use of "with" expressing *accompaniment* includes a second noun in the action, as if it were the subject, or near, allied, or akin to the subject:

"**She was walking around *with* her friend Mary.**"

"**I woke up *with* the others at the first light of dawn.**"

Answer (score -1):

It sounds as if the legs were found to be dangling upon their owner's waking. That sounds more like "accompaniment" than "manner". The sleeper didn't wake himself by means of dangling his legs.
But the meaning of the phrase seems clear enough, however you categorize it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The issue with this sentence was found during translation, as the translator is not sure whether if the dangling happened after or before, or at the same time the sleeper woke up. As we can't literally translate the word "with" in our language in this case, the before-after detail is rather important. I figure that knowing the semantic role of the adverb clause here would help clarifying the confusion, as accompaniment clause would mean the dangling happened along side the waking, not after it. I look forward to your continued discussion on this. Thank you very much!

Comment: As I read it, in that sentence, *with* means that the waking led to the discovery of dangling legs, indicating simultaneity.

Comment: To clarify, the sentence has no information about when the legs started dangling, and no implication that dangling caused the wakeup.

Comment: You have to use knowledge of how people sleep, rather than relying on the grammar.